# YouTube video stream in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, video-player

We have Unity educational crossplatform app. We have to play videos from our server or youtube via Unity VideoPlayer without downloading video. We are plaing video from server addin to video link '.mp4'. But there is no posibility to do that for youtube, cause it doesn't have a link for video, but for youtube page.

We tried adding '.mp4' to youtube link but it doesn't work